# How to change subtitle of annotation when selected?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Ive got a few annotation on a map that is loaded.  I know how to get the distance from the annotation to the users location and want to be able to show it in the subtitle when the user selects it.

I thought I could do it here.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

But the problem is I can't assign a new subtitle because it complains that it is readonly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can calculate the distance before adding the annotations to the map and so add the subtitle to the annotation then add the annotation to the map

Comment: Thats true, the problem I am facing is when the user is moving I want to recalculate the distance.

Comment: Then when the user select an annotation, you will need to remove the current annotation and add a new one and make it selected

Comment: Can you please show the code you tried in didSelectAnnotationView?  Are you using a custom annotation class or the generic MKPointAnnotation?

Comment: I was using generic.  The code was just setting the title property to something new

Comment: Was the code doing `view.annotation.subtitle = @"something";` or were you first casting it to `MKPointAnnotation *` and then setting subtitle?

Comment: Correct.  It was view.annotation.subtitle = @"something";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, the code you tried is something like this:

```
view.annotation.subtitle = @"something";
```

The compiler will give the error "Assignment to readonly property" here because the `annotation` property of `MKAnnotationView` is typed as the generic `id <MKAnnotation>`.

The `MKAnnotation` protocol defines `subtitle` as readonly as the *default*.

The `MKPointAnnotation` class (which you are using for your annotations according to another comment) implements `MKAnnotation` but *overrides* `subtitle` as write-able.

To avoid the compiler error, you need to cast `view.annotation` to `MKPointAnnotation` (which in your case it really is).  For example:

```
if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
{
    MKPointAnnotation *pa = (MKPointAnnotation *)view.annotation;
    pa.subtitle = @"something";
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was that simple.  I was trying pretty much everything under the sun, from deleting and recreating annotations in the exact same spot and programmatically selecting them.   Thanks so much for the help and the clear explanation on why it was happening.